# how to avoid exponents in android eclipse calculation results in a text string?

Tags: android, string, floating-point, double

in android eclipse sometimes a calculation result for both double and float when displayed as a string uses a decimal point (desired) but sometimes using an exponent (bad - confusing to user).  anyway to avoid the exponent?

Comment: normal desired display = 0.000680011 for example.  exponent display = 6.680011E-4 indicating 4 added zeros on front of the percentage number.

Answer (score 1):

See [`String.format`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) documentation.

Just set the desired format for your numbers. You probably want `String.format("%f",number)`.

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with string formatting in general, you should check out this link as well http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html

Comment: where within ECLIPSE does the String.format go?  somewhere in XMS resource?

Comment: No. What do you do to display the number?

Comment: ...first, thanks for your answer... i put the String instruction in the code for the ONCLICK without a compile error.  still testing.  however, another java bug puts the special characters 'right colon' and 'asterisk'  ')' and '*'  whenever the string ends in an 8 or 9 respectively.  trying to write andoid app for first time  the app in C# as windows dialog was lot easier.

Comment: Alright, I think that new bug is weird, and deserves its own question. Also there's no way to know what's going on without seeing the relevant code.

Comment: String pdecimal = Double.toString(guess); pdecimal = pdecimal.replace('*','9');
     pdecimal = pdecimal.replace(')','8');text2.setText(pdecimal);....here's code...note i did string replacement to get rid of ) and * but that still leaves math result skewed.   using GANAMEDE ECLIPSE.  is HELIOS better?

Comment: Has nothing to do with eclipse version. Does `String pdecimal = String.format("%f",guess);` give the same results?

Comment: whenever i run with the String.format("%f",guess);  ...it compiles ok but blows up on that instruction.  used %d on a double = same thing.

Comment: within debug guess looks ok, a big decimal number like 0.0000587.

Comment: what do you mean by "blows up"?

Comment: "application has stopped unexpectedly" usually means an op has tried to do a calculation on bad data.  i've tried the format both with and without editing out the ")" and '*'.

Comment: you should use a debugger to figure out what's going on

Comment: pdecimal = pdecimal.replace('*','9');
     pdecimal = pdecimal.replace(')','8');
     String.format("%1.5f",pdecimal); <<--IT STOPPED (BLEW) ON THIS      pdecimal contained '0.008'

Comment: Of course it did. Why are you trying to pass a String to a function that takes a number?

Comment: 0.008505893553690233 <<--'guess' value looks same before and after String.format("%f",guess); <<-instruction...after instruction-->String pdecimal = Double.toString(guess);...pdecimal looks like this-->>0.00).....all above after feeding a number not a string to the format instruction.

Comment: just a note the other 3 numberic fields behave normally.  maybe the really long 'guess' value causes the ')'...i'll try truncating it.